# Woocommerce Extending WC_Order class to override a function definition

Tags: woocommerce

I want to change a function definition by extending WC_Order class. But it gives an "Unable to create order" error. How can I properly extend WC_Order class?

I created a class as below:

```html
class AWCDP_Payment extends WC_Order{
 function get_created_via($context = 'view'){
        return 'admin';
      }
}
```

and used as below:

```html
$partial_payment = new AWCDP_Payment();
$partial_payment->add_item($item);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hey @Sanesh! Could you please include in your question how you have extended the `WC_Order` class and how you are instantiating it? Your code will help figuring out what is going on.

Comment: Hi Diego, thanks for your reply. I have updated my question, please check.

Comment: Great! Where do you instantiate the `AWCDP_Payment` class exactly? Is it in a hook or a template? Which one?

Comment: The AWCDP_Payment is instantiated from a function inside another Class file in my plugin file. My intention was to create a new order along with normal order and only change some values from the original order.

Comment: Do you know what hook (filter, action, etc.) you are using?

Comment: I'm using the "woocommerce_create_order" hook.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. In order to be able to reproduce the error you're getting, we probably need to see the actual implementation of the class and hook. Can you please post them?